# Show that $(x^2-2)(x^2-17)(x^2-34)=0$ has a root in the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am looking at this case where the Local-to-Global Principle does not hold. This is a problem in Katok's book, *$p$-adic Analysis Compared with Real*, (Exercise 46).

> Show that $$(x^2-2)(x^2-17)(x^2-34)=0 \qquad (\star)$$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$ and in the $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$, but no solution in $\mathbb{Q}$.

One can quickly verify that that $(\star)$ has roots in $\mathbb{R}$ since $\pm\sqrt{2}$, $\pm\sqrt{17}$, and $\pm\sqrt{34}=\pm\sqrt{2}\sqrt{17}$ are irrational. Moreover, this also shows that $(\star)$ does not have a root in $\mathbb{Q}$.

How does one go about show that $(\star)$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for all primes $p$? Does one need to apply Hensel's Lemma here?

Comment: Perhaps use quadratic recriprocity to show there's a root in $\mathbb{Z}/p$ for all $p$ and then use Hensel.  But, I didn't check if these statements are true.

Comment: As @MichaelBurr said, assume that $x^{2} \equiv a$ has a solution mod $p$. Then you can lift it to the solution in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ by using Hensel's lemma. If you can't find such solution for both $a=2$ and $a=17$, then there exists a solution for $a=34$ since $$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{17}{p}\right) = \left{34}{p}\right).$$ (Maybe there's some things to check for $p=2$ and $p=17$.)